# NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am running XCode 9.4.1 and my code is not starting the simulator run.

Simulator.log says

Simulator[2601] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge

Version is - Version 10 (SimulatorApp-851.2 CoreSimulator-518.22).

Sometime the iPhone screen shows up but in either case, Xcode collapses with pop up saying -

"The app could not be installed at this time."

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log, the rest of that error should be visible and provide you with actionable data (eg: bundle identifier problems, etc)